# How to get a json object within a mysqli_fetch_assoc while in php

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to generate a json object within a mysqli_fetch_assoc query in a while like:

```
        while ( $paises = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $get ) ) :
            $country = array( 
                $paises['pais'] => properties::get_city($paises['pais'] ) 
            );
            echo json_encode( $country, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
        endwhile;
```

The result of this is:

```
{"MX":"México"}{"AR":"Argentina"}{"ES":"España"}{"UY":"Uruguay"}{"PY":"Paraguay"}{"CL":"Chile"}{"EC":"Ecuador"}{"BO":"Bolivia"}{"DE":"Alemania"}{"US":"Estados Unidos"}
```

But this is wrong, becasuse the result that I expect is:

```
{"MX":"México","AR":"Argentina","ES":"España","UY":"Uruguay","PY":"Paraguay","CL":"Chile","EC":"Ecuador","BO":"Bolivia","DE":"Alemania","US":"Estados Unidos"}
```

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: `$country = array( $paises['pais'] => properties::get_city($paises['pais'] ));` need to change to `$country[$paises['pais']] = properties::get_city($paises['pais'] ) ;`

Comment: Hi! Mmm... Is not working, your code is giving me a triplicate json result

Comment: Yes, you are telling me that I need to change for $country[$paises['pais']] = properties::get_city($paises['pais'] ) ; my array, but if I do it, the result is: the same but this repeat for tree times more... The issue is because the json is generate within my while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes are commented:-

```
 $country = array(); // define an empty array i think you already have

while ( $paises = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $get ) ) :
   $country[$paises['pais']] = properties::get_city($paises['pais']); // assign key-value pair to the array
endwhile;

echo json_encode( $country, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ); // put json encoding code outside of loop.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is not working yet. This have an error and this says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 120 I think that there is a missing a semicolon in the expression but i don't see that.

Comment: @FernandoUrban one `)` missed. check now.

Comment: Ok! The answer is up-vote and thanks for your help! Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$countries = array();

while ( $paises = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $get ) ) :
  // i assume that "$paises['pais']" for the first row is "MX" and "properties::get_city()" returns "Mexico"
  $countries[$paises['pais']] = properties::get_city($paises['pais']);
endwhile;

echo json_encode( $countries, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is not working yet. This have an error and this says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 120 I think that there is a missing a semicolon in the expression but i don't see that.

Comment: jkobus  your code have two errors 1. missing `)` and 2. use of two different variables `$countries` and `$country`